# Three way duel simulator working incorrectly

Tags: c++

I am creating a three way duel simulator. Each person has a precision level (Aaron's is 33, Bob's is 50, and Charles's is 100). A random number between 1 and 100 is generated, and if that number is less than the person's skill level, then that person shoots the other (alive) player with the highest skill level. It is supposed to repeat 10000 times, and I am going to print the results. However, the scores for each person are incorrect. I keep getting Bob's score to be 10000, while the others are 0. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std; 

bool at_least_two_alive (bool A_alive, bool B_alive, bool C_alive) {

int i = 0;

if (A_alive) {
    i++;
}
if (B_alive) {
    i++;
}
if (C_alive) {
    i++;
}
if (i >= 2) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

void Aaron_shoots (bool& B_alive, bool& C_alive ) {

int Aaron_precision = 33;

int shoot_target_result = rand()%100;

if (shoot_target_result <= Aaron_precision) {

    if (C_alive) {
        C_alive = false;
    }

    else {
        B_alive = false;
    }

}
}

void Bob_shoots (bool& A_alive, bool& C_alive ) {

int Bob_precision = 50;

int shoot_target_result = rand()%100;

if (shoot_target_result <= Bob_precision) {

    if (C_alive) {
        C_alive = false;
    }

    else {
        A_alive = false;
    }
}
}

void Charles_shoots (bool& A_alive, bool& B_alive ) {

int Charles_precision = 100;

int shoot_target_result = rand()%100;

if (shoot_target_result <= Charles_precision) {

    if (B_alive) {
        B_alive = false;
    }

    else {
        A_alive = false;
    }
}
}

void duel() {

bool A_alive = true;
bool B_alive = true;
bool C_alive = true;
int A_wins = 0;
int B_wins = 0;
int C_wins = 0;
int number_of_duels = 10000;

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_duels; i++) {
    while (at_least_two_alive(A_alive, B_alive, C_alive)) {
        if (A_alive) {
            Aaron_shoots(B_alive, C_alive);
        }
        if (B_alive ) {
            Bob_shoots(A_alive, C_alive);
        }
        if (C_alive ) {
            Charles_shoots(A_alive, B_alive);
        }
    }
    if (A_alive) {
        A_wins++;
    }
    if (B_alive ) {
        B_wins++;
    }
    if (C_alive ) {
        C_wins++;
    }
}
}

void menu() {
string input;
cout << "\n*** Welcome to Duel Simulator ***\n\n"
        "Ready to run Duel Simulator (run 10000 times)? (y/n): ";

cin >> input;

if (input == "y") {
    cout << "\n1000 duels completed"
    "\n2000 duels completed"
    "\n3000 duels completed"
    "\n4000 duels completed"
    "\n5000 duels completed"
    "\n6000 duels completed"
    "\n7000 duels completed"
    "\n8000 duels completed"
    "\n9000 duels completed"
    "\n10000 duels completed";
    duel();
}
else {
    if (input == "n") {
        menu();
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a valid option!\n";
        menu();

    }

}
}

int main () {

menu();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the flags before running each duels.

Move

```
bool A_alive = true;
bool B_alive = true;
bool C_alive = true;
```

to right after the beginning of the `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_duels; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll pardon my being blunt, this doesn't strike me as particularly wonderful code. I think I'd write something more like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class generator {
    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni;
public:
    generator(int low, int high) : rng(std::random_device()()), uni(low, high) { }
    int operator()() { return uni(rng); }
} gen(1, 100);

class duelist {
    std::string name;
    int skill;
    bool dead;
public:
    duelist(std::string const &name, int skill) 
        : name(name), 
        skill(skill), 
        dead(false)
    {
    }

    void round(std::vector<duelist> &competitors) { 
        if (dead) return;
        int value = gen();

        auto c = competitors.rbegin();
        while (*this == *c || c->dead) {
            ++c;
            if (c == competitors.rend())
                return;
        }

        std::cout << name << " shoots ";
        if (value < skill) {
            std::cout << "and kills: " << *c << "\n";
            c->dead = true;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "and misses\n";
    }

    operator bool() const { return !dead; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, duelist const &d) { return os << d.name; }

    // sorts in descending order by skill
    bool operator<(duelist const &other) const { return skill < other.skill; }
private:

    // but comparison for equality is by name
    bool operator==(duelist const &other) const { return name == other.name; }
};

bool at_least_two(std::vector<duelist> const &competitors) {
    return std::count_if(competitors.begin(), competitors.end(), [](bool b) { return b; }) > 1;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<duelist> init { { "Aaron", 33 }, { "Bob", 50 }, { "Charles", 100 } };

    std::sort(init.begin(), init.end());

    std::vector<int> wins(init.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        std::vector<duelist> competitors = init;

        while (at_least_two(competitors)) {
            for (auto c : competitors)
                c.round(competitors);
            for (int i = 0; i < competitors.size(); i++)
                if (competitors[i])
                    ++wins[i];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Survival stats: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < init.size(); i++)
        std::cout << init[i] << " : " << wins[i] << "\n";
}
```

For example, if we want to model a 4-way duel instead of 3-way, this lets us do that simply by adding another duelist to `init`:

```
std::vector<duelist> init { { "Aaron", 33 }, { "Bob", 50 }, { "Charles", 100 }, { "Cassie", 80 } };
```